# Can we use MariaDB mysqldump CLI to take dump from MySQL Community version?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.3

MySQL server version:

> mysqld Ver 5.7.26 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

MariaDB mysqldump CLI version:

> mysqldump Ver 10.17 Distrib 10.3.12-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)

I am using this mysqldump version to take dump from the mentioned mysqld version. Data is around 25 gb.

I am getting below error while importing the dump,

> ERROR 3105 (HY000) at line 82: The value specified for generated
>   column 'column_name' in table 'table_name' is not allowed.

Source and destination mysql server is same version.

Command used to dump,

```
mysqldump -h mysql -P 3306 -uroot -px xxxxxxx --databases db_name
```

Total number of characters in Line 82 is around 80k, line starts with,

> INSERT INTO `table_name` (`ID`, `XXXXX`, `XXXXX`, `XXXXX`,
>   `XXXXX`, `XXXXX`, `XXXXX`, `XXXXX`, `XXXXX`,
>   `XXXXX`, `xxxxx`, `xxxxx`, `XXXXX`) VALUES
>   (5541,1,4852,'2018-11-12 09:30:25.306','{\"id\": 1108

Output from show create table, for the column throwing error:

> `column_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS
>   AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`OPTIONS`,'$.type'))) VIRTUAL,

Can we use MariaDB mysqldump CLI to take dump from MySQL Community version?

Comment: Ended up not using MariaDB CLI https://github.com/karthikeayan/mysql-backup/blob/master/debian-mysql-core/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

[MariaDB JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/) are different from MySQL ones.

1. Manually create the equivalent table in MariaDB-10.3.
2. remove the `DROP TABLE {tablename}` /`CREATE TABLE {tablename}` from your `mysqldump` output.
3. import the edited mysqldump file.

If there are a lot of these generated columns, suggest doing a `mysqldump --no-data` and getting the syntax of all the tables correct first.